# Is a reliable, monotonic time source available in Hyper-V guests to do benchmarking?

Tags: java, linux, benchmarking, hyper-v, sigar

Hyper-V guests encounter horrible clock drifts. If I my memory does not fail me, I saw drifts of many seconds over the course of only a few minutes, if not less. And I'm not talking about cases where the system is hibernated etc.

I'd like to benchmark a Java app inside such a system, measuring the processing time of individual messages that enter and leave the system. Processing time of a single message is expected to be between 500 microseconds to 3000 microseconds (there's some io involved).

I'm fine with native .so libraries if necessary. The guest systems in question will be linux machines with probably 2.8.x kernels, 64bit.

A post I found on [System.nanoTime in Hyper-V guests](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.jp/2009/03/time-running-backwards-in-microsoft.html) was not encouraging.

Hoping that perhaps `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` might come to my rescue, I grepped for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in the [Sigar](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) sources, but that did not turn up anything.

Any ideas? Or is this a hopeless endeavor?

Comment: You should be running the benchmark on a physical machine, different from the VM host. It is never wise to run the benchmarking software on the same machine as the one being benchmarked. Also, this way you'd be also taking the latency added by the virtualized networking too - which is useful as it seems that you're trying to figure out the overhead of the virtualization system used...

Comment: I'd like to avoid making this benchmarking problem a distributed one, involving more than one machine due to the added complexity involved. And if we are talking timing individual messages, this also means adding network communication for every single message, with a potentially significant impact on the performance of the system to be benchmarked.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted something: so the messages entering and leaving the system don't come from the network?

Comment: Yes, they do, but they come and go from and to different places, i.e. there is not one machine that sends and receives and would be able to time easily.

Comment: So machine A sends a request, your server processes it, and sends a reply to machine B - where A and B are separate machines - and the communication is asynchronous in the sense that machine A does not get any reply from your server when the message was completely processed, but rather instantly, as it was completely received?